# Quarkus Reactive SQL clients how to make sure my api is reactive

Tags: quarkus, reactive

I have a question, I am just starting on reactive programing and I am using quarkus. I made a demo with Panache hibernate reactive and one with SQL clients.
I want each of my rest apis to run on a different non blocking thread. With panache hibernate whenever I did a a blocking action I got a message about it and in the logs it showed me that the api was running o vertex event loop thread so everything was fine.
In Reactive clients everything runs on executor thread 0 does that mean my apis aren’t asynchonus(reactive) from input to output and when I run a blocking action non erros is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus tries in a lot of places to put the proper guard-rails when it comes to the threads that can be used - however it can't catch all mistakes.

If you are seeing your code executed on a thread that has `executor` in the name, then the request is being serviced by the wrong thread pool.
If you are using `quarkus-resteasy` for example, this is the only way that RESTEasy can handle requests - it doesn't matter what your code is, the request is always handled on an executor thread.
For this reason, Quarkus provides RESTEasy Reactive (which is the prefered REST API layer) which allows you to choose whether you want a request to be serviced on an executor thread or an event-loop thread.
See [this](https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/) for more details.

Comment: i have:
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy-mutiny'
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-reactive-pg-client'
 
should i configure pool thread or is it done by the quarkus behind the shene what should i do to have just a simple api reactive input ot output (i am following the SQL client quides of quarkus)

Comment: Thread pools are configured by Quarkus, you should not configure you own. In any case, for anyone to make a more meaningful suggestion, you would need to update your question with some sample code.